# Copying every row of one matrix to every row of another empty matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

How can i get to perform an operation on a every row in a matrix and copy it to another matrix? data1 and data2 are matrix with size suppose n*4 and i need to add 1 to each element.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
data1=np.matrix('1 1 1 1;2 2 2 2;3 3 3 3;4 4 4 4')
row1=np.matrix('1 1 1 1')
for row in data1:
    row=row+row1
    print(row)
//The results is as below
//[[2 2 2 2]]
//[[3 3 3 3]]
//[[4 4 4 4]]
//[[5 5 5 5]]
```

The second matrix data2 should contain all the elements from matrix data1 after row manipulation. The print statement gives expected result but how do i copy these rows to a new matrix?

Comment: Could you please format the code with proper indentation and inside code blocks

Comment: `for i in alist: i = i+1` does not change the values in `alist`.  This is a fundamental Python iteration issue.

Comment: Small correction it is not 1 but it is a row matrix.

Comment: Please provide example inputs (using proper python syntax) for `data1` and `data2`

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason to use `np.matrix`? I think you'll have a better time sticking with `np.array`... this is in the `np.matrix` docs: *"It is no longer recommended to use this class, even for linear algebra. Instead use regular arrays. The class may be removed in the future."* You really should switch to using arrays

Comment: `row=row+row1` still doesn't change the `row` in the source `data1`.  The accepted answer avoids all iteration, which is fine.  But the problem with your iteration is a basic Python issue, which you'll need to understand soon or later.

Comment: @hpaulj if `alist=[[1],[2],[3]]` then `for i in alist: i[0]=i[0]+1` will though, not that it's a good idea...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

data1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4],
                  [5,6,7,8]])

mu = [1,1,1,1]

data2 = data1 + mu
```

Or if you actually just want to add `1` to every element:

```
data2 = data1 + 1
```

Or if `data1` is just a list of lists then use a nested list comprehension:

```
mu = [1,1,1,1]
data1 = [[1,2,3,4],
         [5,6,7,8]]
data2 = [[r+m for r,m in zip(row,mu)] for row in data1]
```

Comment: If you can get away with using numpy, this is the right solution. It is much faster and for operations like these, simpler. In addition to the array type numpy has a matrix type which follows matrix multiplication rules. So data1*data2 would multiply element by element if they are arrays, but if you choose the np.matrix type data1*data2.T will transpose data2 to get the correct shapes for matrix multiplication (2,4) * (4,2) then do matrix multiplication.

Comment: @velotron but you should not be using the matrix type anymore, even for linear algebra. You can do matrix multiplication with arrays: `data1 @ data2.T`

Comment: @Dan thanks for pointing that out. The matrix type does have other useful syntax. For instance data2.I will return the inverse of the matrix. You can do the same thing on an array with numpy.linalg.inv(x), but the .I notation is nice.  However, TIL that [matrix is deprecated](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html#array-or-matrix-which-should-i-use). Thanks!